# Problem with Button. I want to hold down on an image and drag it to an specific location, which should open an activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat

Honestly I dont know how to proceed. I looked up some feeds on this website and got a bit confused. The imageview button should be invisibly dragged at the specific location of an other image and as long as my pressed thumb relocates to the other image, a activity should be called. In an earlier version, the activity was functional but not while moving the button while it is hold down with my thumb. Hopefully someone knows an answer for this (for me very challenging question.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (imageRect == null) {
            imageRect = new Rect();
            imageView2.getGlobalVisibleRect(imageRect);
        }
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        if (imageRect.contains(x, y)) {
            openActivity();
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        detectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListener());
        imageViewPlayButton = findViewById(R.id.PlayButton_Image_White_Base);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.register_Icon_Base);
        imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.navigation_Background_Image_Register);
        imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.Login_Icon_Base);

        imageViewPlayButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: The `MotionEvent` contains x and y position information of where your thumb is touching it. With that you have to set the x and y position of you image view to make it drag.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The Motion / new position of my thumb gets noticed by the programm. The only problem is, that it doenst recognizes that I am on the other Imageview, which should trigger the activity. Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe return `false` in `onTouch` so that the touch event isn't consumed by the child view.

Comment: Yes this works but not 100% right, now the menu which should pop out while I press on Button stays also if I press the Button not. The other Problem is than solved but now this exists

Comment: Then return true in `onTouchEvent`?

Comment: No same problem :/

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to help further without more code for context

Comment: Look at my answer, I posted my class there, is all what I have :sweat_smile:

Comment: I cannot see the code for the menu you mention

Comment: Okay. The OnTouchListener triggers the visibility of the other 3 imageviews, while my thumb is pressed down on screen. After dragging the ,,main" imageview onto another image, a activity should be executed which transfers the user into a new activity. But the problem is, that in one way the activity works but the buttons dont get invisible afterwards vise versa.

Comment: I'm sorry it's really hard to understand your English. Maybe you could post some screenshots to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.RemoteInput;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.media.effect.Effect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageViewPlayButton, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4;
    private Rect imageRect;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        detectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListener());
        imageViewPlayButton = findViewById(R.id.PlayButton_Image_White_Base);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.register_Icon_Base);
        imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.navigation_Background_Image_Register);
        imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.Login_Icon_Base);

        imageViewPlayButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (imageRect == null) {
            imageRect = new Rect();
            imageView2.getGlobalVisibleRect(imageRect);
        }
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        if (imageRect.contains(x, y)) {
            openActivity();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void openActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

}
```